# How can I get the cdate field from a Date object?

Tags: java, date, private-members, java.util.date

Does anyone know how to grab or create the cdate value from Date? I haven't been able to figure out how to do so and I don't know how to necessarily get it.  In the Date class it is there as
   `private transient BaseCalendar.Date cdate;` I don't see an option to grabt the field from the Date object itself.

I am setting this date using `request.setGatewayEndTime(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());` 
where the calendar is from the java.util.Calendar import

[debug pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwVdr.png)

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why do you think you need the `cdate` field? That is an implementation detail that is intentionally not exposed to the end user. What kind of information do you hope to get from that? Generally speaking, you should try to avoid using `java.util.Data` and `java.util.Calendar` whenever you can and use the modern `java.time` API instead.

Comment: If you want the string value shown in the debugger, use a SimpleDateFormat (or, as suggested, DateTimeFormatter)

Comment: @JoachimSauer oh thanks for the feed back I didn't know that as I am just playing around with java

Comment: It looks like what you *actually* want to do (the X of your XY problem) is format a `Date` object in ISO-8601 format.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead depending on your exact needs use for example `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

As commented, trying to access internally defined fields that were intentionally hidden from outside calling programmers would be unwise.

As commented, you seem to have an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I'll take a stab at what you might need.

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `Calendar`, `Date`, etc.

You claim to have a call to a method requiring a `java.util.Date` object that represents the current moment as seen in UTC, that is, with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. To capture the current moment, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;  // Current moment as seen with an offset of zero.
```

I suggest you educate the author of that called method about how `Date` has been replaced by `Instant`.

Until they update their API, you can easily convert between legacy and modern classes by calling conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date d = Date.from( now ) ;
request.setGatewayEndTime( d );
```

As for the `BaseCalendar.Date` field, if your goal is to get a string in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format similar to the string you show in your screenshot which is nearly in standard format but omits the COLON from between the hours and minutes of the offset, then simply call `Instant#toSting`. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 format by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
String output = now.toString() ;  // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

Your screenshot uses another offset other than zero. If you wish to see a moment with the offset of a particular time zone, apply a [`ZoneID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) object to produce a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/La_Paz" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = now.atZone( z ) ;
```

Produce text in standard ISO 8601 format that has been wisely extended to include the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```